# Autoscroll CheckedListBox with DragDrop reordering

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I just implemented a drag drop reordering function for a CheckedListBox. Now I want it to scroll down if dragging outside the bottom and vice versa at the top (a normal dragdrop autoscroll)

I've found loads of WPF info, but I don't see how I can apply those solutions to my winform ChekedListBox.

Here's my code:

```
        private void myListBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

            Point point = myListBox.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            int index = myListBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
            int selectedIndex = myListBox.SelectedIndex;

            if (index < 0)
            {
                index = selectedIndex;
            }

            if (index != selectedIndex)
            {
                myListBox.SwapItems(selectedIndex, index);
                myListBox.SelectedIndex = index;
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the [CheckedListBox.TopIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.topindex.aspx) property within the [Timer.Tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event handler to implement the auto-scroll feature. To start and stop the timer, use the [CheckedListBox.DragLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave.aspx) and [CheckedListBox.DragEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter.aspx) events. Here is a code snippet:

```
private void checkedListBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    scrollTimer.Stop();
}

private void checkedListBox1_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    scrollTimer.Start();
}

private void scrollTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Point cursor = PointToClient(MousePosition);
    if (cursor.Y < checkedListBox1.Bounds.Top)
        checkedListBox1.TopIndex -= 1;
    else if (cursor.Y > checkedListBox1.Bounds.Bottom)
        checkedListBox1.TopIndex += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like a bit hacky, but very clever implementation... and it works!

Comment: Only one problem though.. if I release the mouse button while scrolling (outside the listbox), the Ticker will stay in started mode.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up adding this to my DragOver event handler instead. Maybe not as slick, but it works a bit better for me.

```
 private void myListBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;

        Point point = myListBox.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        int index = myListBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
        int selectedIndex = myListBox.SelectedIndex;

        if (index < 0)
        {
            index = selectedIndex;
        }

        if (index != selectedIndex)
        {
            myListBox.SwapItems(selectedIndex, index);
            myListBox.SelectedIndex = index;
        }

        if (point.Y <= (Font.Height*2))
        {
            myListBox.TopIndex -= 1;
        }
        else if (point.Y >= myListBox.Height - (Font.Height*2))
        {
            myListBox.TopIndex += 1;
        }
    }
```